# What can cause problems with displaying text from Image when I save it to .tiff?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is code, what I use to save Image to .tiff file:

```
var encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((myImage.Source as DrawingImage).ToBitmapSource()));
using FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
encoder.Save(stream);
```

Here is extension for DrawingImage, which converts DrawingImage to BitmapSource:

```
public static class DrawingImageExtension
{
    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this DrawingImage source)
    {
        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        drawingContext.DrawImage(source, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(source.Width, source.Height)));
        drawingContext.Close();

        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)source.Width, (int)source.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

It works, but when I try to save a large image, part of the text stops being displayed. I add the text to the picture as follows:

```
private GlyphRunDrawing GetGlyphVertex(string str)
    {
        var emSize = 10;
        var glyphIndices = new ushort[str.Length];
        var advanceWidths = new double[str.Length];
        double strWidth = 0, strHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            var glyphIndex = font.CharacterToGlyphMap[str[i]];
            glyphIndices[i] = glyphIndex;
            advanceWidths[i] = font.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * emSize;
            strWidth += advanceWidths[i];
            if (i == 0) strHeight = font.AdvanceHeights[glyphIndex] * emSize;
        }
        var baselineOrigin = new Point(...); //It doesn't matter
        var glyphRun = new GlyphRun(
        font, 0, false, emSize,
        glyphIndices, baselineOrigin, advanceWidths,
        null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return new GlyphRunDrawing(textColor, glyphRun);
    }
```

Then I just add this GlyphRunDrawing to common DrawingGroup.
Here is the part of the big picture with which the problem arises:

[image: Problem]

From some point until the end of the image, the text stops being displayed. With smaller pictures, everything works correctly. What could be the problem?

Comment: As a note, you should be writing `using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen()) { drawingContext.DrawImage(...); }`

Comment: Also do not use the `as` operator without checking the result for null. Replace `(myImage.Source as DrawingImage).ToBitmapSource()` with `((DrawingImage)myImage.Source).ToBitmapSource()`

Comment: You could also write `new Rect(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height)`.

Comment: Under the hood, drawing in Windows is most likely done using GDI+, which cannot create a drawing surface from a huge image. There are workarounds as explained in [this forum post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/m51903-). Another possibility you might be [running out of GDI objects](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-8211-part-2/ba-p/723897)